# Probability distribution in np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed, probability-distribution

The numpy function np.random.choice takes in an optional parameter called 'p' that denotes the probability distribution of the values it is sampling . So , my question is , even though the function generates random values , do values that have higher probability more likely to be sampled ? Meaning , does it randomly choose a value from a subset of " Most probable values " ?

Am I right in perceiving it that way  ? Or can someone please correct my assumption  ?

Comment: Yes, it's a [Discrete distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution)

Comment: that's exactly what it means, yes. if you have `a` at  `0.9` and `b` at `0.1`, then `a` is likely to be chosen 9 times more often than `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an optional array of probabilities `p` with which respective elements of sampled array `A` are sampled. So `A` and `p` should have the same number of elements and all elements of `p` should add up to 1 (as all discrete probabilities should).